# To get listbox selected values in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In asp.net Mvc3 razor, I have binded some data with dbcontext in my controller viewbag using selectlist

My controller..

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.students = new SelectList(db.StudentList, "StudentID", "StudentName");
            return View();
        }
```

Then I binded it to the ListBox using viewbag

My View..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Student"))
{    
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div>
     @Html.ListBox("students")
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Save" />
    </p>
    </div>
}
```

Now, in my controller, in that Save action, I need to capture the listbox selected values
I have tried the following

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Save(FormCollection formValue) 
        {
            //need code to capture values                
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Could anyone help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
 @Html.ListBox("students",ViewBag.students )
```

From form collection get the value of 'students'. For that please refer the following page

[Pulling ListBox selected items from FormCollection](http://forums.asp.net/t/1706029.aspx/1)

For a nice implementation of listbox in MVC please read this article.

[ASP.NET MVC Select List Example](http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/views/asp-net-mvc-select-list-example)

Comment: here I need to bind data to the listbox from database

Comment: Please read the last article. In that article see how data is filled in GetOptions() method. Instead of filling the hardcode value enumerate through table rows and fill data.

Comment: In your code in the following line replace the code as ViewBag.students = new SelectList(getStudents(), "StudentID", "StudentName");   Then make a method as getStudents which return studentID and studentName values from DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Student/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var studentList = new List<Student>
                              {
                                  new Student {StudentID = 1, StudentName = "StudentName1"},
                                  new Student {StudentID = 2, StudentName = "StudentName2"},
                                  new Student {StudentID = 3, StudentName = "StudentName3"},
                                  new Student {StudentID = 4, StudentName = "StudentName4"}
                              };

        ViewBag.students = new SelectList(studentList, "StudentID", "StudentName");
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(String[] students)
    {
        return View();
    }

}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: here I need to bind data from database

Comment: It is sample data, behavior the data will be definitely same, i don't want to post very huge db code to that question.